# Error: AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'driver'

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver

> ```py
> from selenium import webdriver
> from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
> from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
> from self import self
>
>
> class Demo:
> def new_login(self):
> driver = webdriver.Chrome()
> driver.get("https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/web/index.php/auth/login")
> driver.maximize_window()
>
> def new_tests(self):
> self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@placeholder='Username']").send_key("Admin")
>
>
> obj = Demo
> obj.new_login(self)
> obj.new_tests(self)
> ```

Trying to run this code, I am facing an error:

`Error: AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'driver'`

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Please properly indent your code. https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help. Also post the whole traceback. `from self import self`: don't use names that are "reserved".

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be as following:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


class Demo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = None

    def new_login(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.driver.get("https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/web/index.php/auth/login")
        self.driver.maximize_window()

    def new_tests():
        self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@placeholder='Username']").send_key("Admin")


obj = Demo()
obj.new_login()
obj.new_tests()
```